# Markov: Expected time of first visit to a state starting from that state.

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

Question: Calculate the expected time of first visit to state 2 given we start in state 2.

Is the answer to this the mean recurrence time of 2 or simply zero?

I at first thought that the answer was zero, since we start in state 2 and therefore take zero time to get there.  But then I thought of the mean recurrence time, and was confused as to what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends exactly on how the first visit to a given state has been defined. In my experience convention says that the answer is zero. If the question asked for the expected return time to state 2 then you would indeed be after the mean recurrence time. Hope this clears things up.

To further clarify the matter:

We define the **hitting time** on i to be
$$ H_i = \inf(n \ge 0:X_n=i), $$
and the **first passage time** to i to be
$$ T_i = \inf(n \ge 1 : X_n =i). $$
Note that we can have a **hitting time of zero**, as in your case, but the first passage time **cannot** be zero. The mean recurrence time is then defined as 
$$ m_i = E_i (T_i) = E(T_i |X_0=i), $$
which is strictly greater than zero.

Comment: @John don't forget to vote up and accept if this is the answer you needed ^_^